# Change the background of the AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i want to know how to change the design of my `AlertDialog`, the buttons the background.

thank you.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Exit")
                .setMessage("Do you want to exit")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_zoom)
                .show();
    }
```

Comment: You can describe more your problem @DesignMan.

Comment: you can create a layout with the design you want and set the same layout in alert dialog.

Comment: yes , but how can i make it like the AlertDialog , i mean how could i define the high and the width of my new layout !

Comment: update your code and show us what you done!

Comment: i'm using the usual code of AlertDialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog_ImageSelector=new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
                    View imageGuideLineInfo=getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_alyout,null);
                    alertDialog_ImageSelector.setView(imageGuideLineInfo);
                    TextView tv_guidelines=(TextView)imageGuideLineInfo.findViewById(R.id.tv_guidelines);
                   final AlertDialog adinfo=alertDialog_ImageSelector.create();
                    adinfo.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));//here you can change the background of alertDialog. 
                    adinfo.show();
```

if you want to change the background of buttons then you need to create the buttons in your_view.xml and bind them here and setBackground.

Comment: could you explain  more for the Buttons; please.

Comment: these buttons you have to create them in your layout and bind them here. see how i did for the TextView. now i can set the background for TextView as tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);in your case it should be Button

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rushi Ayyappa !

Comment: happy coding.!!

Answer (score 0):

use this android inbuilt theme

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT);
```